# Amazon cloudfront custom origin rails with authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webserver, amazon-cloudfront

As far I understand, custom origin server with cloudfront only works if cloudfront is able to access files from my website url:

eg: www.domain.com/hello.html

However, my website has a login requirement in order to view hello.html. How can I have the login mechanism and still cache my real hello.html page in cloudfront using custom origin server?

I am using Ruby on Rails btw, but this is applicable to other stacks as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is not possible. As you said, CloudFront has be to able to access the file to serve and cache it. I never saw an option to tell CloudFront to use a password to access the file.

An idea: maybe you can check in your Rails app, before you require the user to enter a password, if the request comes from CloudFront (I'm sure there are some headers indicating that) and, if so, bypass the login requirement?

Edit:

It says in the [docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html):

```
Do not configure your origin server to request client authentication.
```

One thing I'm pretty sure set though is the User Agent. Check for `user_agent =~ /cloudfront/i`and bypass authentication?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll mark it accepted! Your workaround seems to be the only one that makes easy sense to me for private content usecase..

Comment: the other thing that is also possible.. and which is what im thinking of doing ... is: 1> Update Cloudfront to a CNAME like static.domain.com in my DNS server.. so all static.domain.com/x.html go to cloudfront.. 2> Set up S3 as the origin server and make it inaccessible to anyone but cloudfront and my webserver (secure S3) 3> write files to S3 and generate signed(secure) URLs with N-day expiry programmatically from my Rails site using Amazon API.. this way I can redirect logged-in users to my "signed" URL and force anonymous users to sign in..

Comment: Plus because the signed URL to static.domain.com/x7353936.html expires in a few days.. people cannot use it to bypass login for too long.. which is secure enough for my site.